# Why does arr.map() throw an error when it is invoked as part of a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to implement a recursive function, that returns a particular property value of each object that is found in a nested array of objects. Each iteration will encounter either an object or an array.

While converting a regular function to a recursive function I get a "arr.map is not a function error".

```
var arr = [{squares: Array(9), xIsNext: true, points: 10}, [{squares: Array(9), xIsNext: true, points: 0}, [{squares: Array(9), xIsNext: false, points: -10}]]];
```

Non-recursive:

```
function findObjPoints(arr){
   return arr.map(isaObj) //works fine
}

function isaObj (j)  {
    if (j.points) {
      return j.points;
    } else {
      return j; //returns an array
    }
  } 
findObjPoints(arr)
```

Recursion:

```
function findObjPoints(arr){
   return arr.map(isaObj) //arr.map is not a function error

}

function isaObj (j)  {
    if (j.points) {
      return j.points;
    } else {
      return findObjPoints(j);
    }
  }

findObjPoints(arr)
```

Error message:

```
VM245:2 Uncaught TypeError: arr.map is not a function
    at findObjPoints (<anonymous>:2:15)
    at isaObj (<anonymous>:10:14)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at findObjPoints (<anonymous>:2:15)
    at isaObj (<anonymous>:10:14)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at findObjPoints (<anonymous>:2:15)
    at <anonymous>:14:1
findObjPoints @ VM245:2
isaObj @ VM245:10
findObjPoints @ VM245:2
isaObj @ VM245:10
findObjPoints @ VM245:2
(anonymous) @ VM245:14
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your test function has a name that implies it's for checking whether something "is an object", but in fact it's checking whether the object has a truthy "points" property value. Is that really the intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're checking to see if the value being examined has a "points" property, you're doing it in a way that fails when the value of `j.points` is falsy (like, when it's `0`).

Instead, test with:

```
  if (typeof j === "object" && "points" in j)
```

As it is now, when your code sees that second object with the "points" property set to zero, the test makes the wrong decision.

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking the value to see if it is an array or not with `Array.isArray()`. If it is an array then you can run your map function.

```js
var arr = [{
    squares: Array(9),
    xIsNext: true,
    points: 10
  },
  [{
      squares: Array(9),
      xIsNext: true,
      points: 0
    },
    [{
      squares: Array(9),
      xIsNext: false,
      points: -10
    }]
  ]
];

function findObjPoints(arr) {
  return Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.map(isaObj) : arr;

}

function isaObj(j) {
  if (j.points) {
    return j.points;
  } else {
    return findObjPoints(j);
  }
}

findObjPoints(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Second round on recursion, isaObj returns findObjPoint(j) where j is not an array. Therefore in findObjPoint function, throws error.